# How to fill GridView Async

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, gridview, mvvm

I have a Gridview, in which the columns are controls such as Combobox, Checkbox, etc.
The GridView is bound to a list of objects by the database with Entity Framework, the bind is using the MVVM pattern.
Sometimes, the query brings only few elements, therefore, the load on the Gridview is fast, but there are times when the query brings more than 500 records and the load becomes very, very slow.
Is there any way that the loading go Gridview record by record?

Here my Gridview code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dtgResumen" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnded="dtgResumen_CellEditEnded" GridLinesVisibility="Both" ItemsSource="{Binding LstAvancesCuvs, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True}" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn x:Name="colEstatus" Width="1.4*" Header="ESTATUS" IsFilterable="False" Tag="0">
        <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedIndex="{Binding EstatusCUV, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Cancelada" Foreground="Red" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Content="Activa" Foreground="Green" />
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colId" Width="Auto" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IdCUVExcel}" Header="ID" IsFilterable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colMza" Width="Auto" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Manzana}" Header="MZA" IsFilterable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colLot" Width="Auto" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Lote}" Header="LOT" IsFilterable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colNo" Width="Auto" DataMemberBinding="{Binding NumeroExterior}" Header="No" IsFilterable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colInt" Width="Auto" DataMemberBinding="{Binding NumeroInterior}" Header="INT" IsFilterable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colEdif" Width="Auto" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Edificio}" Header="EDIF" IsFilterable="False" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colAvanceIndividual" Width="*" Background="{Binding ColorAvance}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding AvanceIndividual, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="True" IsReadOnly="True">
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="% Avance Individual" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ColorAvance}" />
            </Style>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellStyle>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colDtu" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DTU, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="DTU" IsFilterable="False">
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="5" Click="CheckBox_Click" IsChecked="{Binding DTU, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colPC" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding PC, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colE" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Estructura, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colIHS" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IHS, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colIE" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IE, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colIG" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IGE, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colAlbanileria" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Albañileria, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colAcabados" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Acabados, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colCHC" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CHC, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colELE" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ELE, Mode=TwoWay}" IsFilterable="False" Tag="1"/>

  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Here my model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<AvanceObra> _lstAvancesCuvs;
    public ObservableCollection<AvanceObra> LstAvancesCuvs
    {
        get { return _lstAvancesCuvs; }
        set
        {
            _lstAvancesCuvs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _lstAvancesCuvs = new ObservableCollection<AvanceObra>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the Telerik component is bind to the model, I don't think that would be possible (bringing records one by one). You can try configing the GridView to page the result. Or alternatively, you can get rid of your MVVM binding and load the data in code behind on demand.

Comment: Will there be any way to optimize the data load? It not necessarily has to be one by one

Comment: Well you have to fill your DataSource async too of course...

Comment: @Richard: Why don't you page it, so the data would be divided into the pages, it will be some sort of lazy behavior so that will be faster.

Comment: @lokusking, I tried but did not work, maybe I did it wrong

Comment: @Transcendent, I do not paginated because the user needs to move quickly

Comment: @Richard Telerik offers a barebones style for their GridView which includes different styles that allow performance boosts.  Look at their documentation.  I was about to cut load time in half when using it.  I was loading ~1400 rows with 8 columns, all which were bound. Also know that the more complex your columns and whats in them, the long it'll take.  Some things that help are doing things like setting a fixed width and enabling column resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an really simple example, on how you can process your actions async:

**XAML-Snippet**

```
<StackPanel >
        <Button Content="FillData" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Files, Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}"></ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class Window1 
    {
        private object _lock = new object();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this.Files, this._lock);

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Files => this._files;

        private ObservableCollection<string> _files = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(yourPath)
                {
                    this.Files.Add(file);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I did this quick and dirty, thats why code-behind.

Notice the `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this.Files, this._lock);`.

This enables the async-mechanism to update your collection from another thread. That should it be.

Have fun

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it!

Comment: Can you please explain yourself? Exceptions? Gui-Freeze?

Comment: @lokusing Mainly it is GUI-Freeze. Sorry absence

Comment: Try removing the setter from `LstAvancesCuvs`. Update your values by `.Clear()` and `.Add()`. Setting whole collections mostly break bindings, which might cause your described side-effect